# Table definition of user type

Tags: sql-server

It  is possible to figure out the table definition of the user defined tabled-type?

There is no column in  sys.types with such info. And sys.modules does not contains info about types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   SELECT *
    FROM sys.columns
    WHERE object_id IN (
      SELECT type_table_object_id
      FROM sys.table_types
      WHERE name = 'some_table_type'
    );
```